# TikZ: Adjust two words among each other by one character

Tags: tikz-pgf, stacking-symbols

I would like to create a logo in LaTeX. Here I need to adjust two words relative to each  other by a chosen letter.

Here is an example, where I'd like to get the two red characters exact among the other:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß},
    Euro={€},
}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0, 0) [above] {Irg\textcolor{red}{e}ndeinWort};
        \node at (0, 0) [below] {Hi\textcolor{red}{e}r};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Do you have an idea how to do this without guessing the right values? Also it would be fine to have a solution independent from font size changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

can be done with a simple tabular. You can also define a new macro for this if you need different texts and colors

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{array,xcolor}

\begin{document} 

{\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{r>{\color{red}}cl}
Irg & e & ndeinWort\\
Hi & e & r
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or if you do not have the same characters

```
\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
    Irgende & i & nWort\\
    Hi \kern0pt& \makebox[0pt]{m} & \kern2.5pt mel\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks! An easy way is always the best one. But often missed.

Comment: This works too. Thank you!
But I tried it with an "l" instead of the "m" and the distances are wrong again. How did you find 0pt and 2.5pt?

Comment: trial and error ... it is not really easy to catch all different combinations of characters with correct spacing

Comment: Ok, I did it this way. Some spaces are good in ex and em, but can only find by trial and error. Thx!